# Accessing image field of line items in Drupal 7 module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am creating custom emails to be sent to customers wanting to share their cart with others. So far, I have each product's quantity, SKU, price, path (node/XYZ), and title. The last item I need in the email is the product's image path.

I found all the other information with the following:

```
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
foreach($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $d => $line_item_wrapper) {
    $sku = $line_item_wrapper->line_item_label->value();
    //...
```

Printing out the following I was able to see a protected "data" property for the wrapper object:

```
print_r($line_item_wrapper->commerce_product);
```

Then, I tried finding the getter method for the field_image property with the following:

```
print_r($line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->getPropertyInfo('field_image');
```

I ended up here with `entity_metadata_field_verbatim_get()` but I don't know what parameters to pass. Also, in the last print statement above I didn't see anything else of value.

I'm wondering if I need to query for this data, and what table / columns to query for? Or maybe use something like `node_load()`? However, i'm not finding it too easy to find the node ID from the line item wrapper.

Comment: If memory serves you should be able to get (for example) the URI with `$line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_image->uri->value())`. You should at the very least have a file id (fid) `$line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_image->raw()` if the image field has a file attached to it, and from there you can use `file_load()`

Comment: The first code sample provided produced errors as there is no `->uri` property for field_image. Once I got the value from `field_image`I had to drill down into an array a bit.

Comment: There's no `uri` property, but usually the entity module will automatically extend the image field into its equivalent file entity, so its properties/fields can be accessed directly. If that's not working it might suggest something isn't set up quite right

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the above problem with this code:

```
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$result = array();

foreach($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $d => $line_item_wrapper) {
    $product = array();
    $product['quantity'] = $line_item_wrapper->quantity->value();
    $product['sku'] = $line_item_wrapper->line_item_label->value();
    $product['path'] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_display_path->value();
    $product['price'] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->value();
    $product['title'] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->title->value();
    $product['image'] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_image->value();
    $product['image'] = $product['image'][0]['filename'];

    array_push($result, $product);
}
```

I have to say, finding all these discrete functions was quite difficult. I did not find any *clear* documentation about Drupal Commerce metadata_wrappers. If anyone could provide further information I'd love to take a look.

In general, I used a lot of `print_r();` to find these values.

Comment: Install [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel), use `dpm()`, and say good riddance to `print_r()` :)